# Why am I getting this LWC error - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setProperty')

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, flow-screen-component

I'm building a Flow Screen Component, however the error "`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setProperty')`" is being displayed below the component when I debug my flow.

Here's my component's JS file:

```js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class DisplayInfoPanel extends LightningElement {
    @api iconName = 'utility:info';
    @api altText;
    @api iconSize = 'small';
    @api richText;
    @api borderColor = 'rgb(0, 112, 210)';
    @api iconForegroundColor = 'initial';
    @api iconBackgroundColor = 'initial';

    isFirstRender = true;
    renderedCallback() {
        if (!this.isFirstRender) {
            return;
        }
        this.isFirstRender = false;

        this.template.host.style.setProperty('--displayInfoPanel-borderColor', this.borderColor);
        this.template.host.style.setProperty('--displayInfoPanel-iconForegroundColor', this.iconForegroundColor);
        this.template.host.style.setProperty('--displayInfoPanel-iconForegroundDefaultColor', this.iconForegroundColor);
        this.template.host.style.setProperty('--displayInfoPanel-iconBackgroundColor', this.iconBackgroundColor);
    }
}
```

HTML file:

```html
<template>
    <div class="displayInfoPanel_container slds-media slds-box">
        <lightning-icon class="slds-media__figure displayInfoPanel_icon" icon-name={iconName} alternative-text={altText} title={altText} size={iconSize}></lightning-icon>
        <lightning-formatted-rich-text class="displayIconWithText_richText slds-media__body" value={richText}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
    </div>
</template>
```

The **setProperty** part of the error points me to the way I'm setting my CSS variables. I was originally setting them like this, which did not produce the error:

```js
document.body.style.setProperty('--displayInfoPanel-borderColor', this.borderColor);
```

However this affected all instances of the component on the screen, which was not desired.

I [found a suggestion](https://forcepanda.wordpress.com/2021/07/27/how-to-dynamically-set-custom-css-properties-in-lwc/comment-page-1/#comment-5025) to use the following code instead, which scopes the function to only the to the individual component:

```js
this.template.host.style.setProperty('--displayInfoPanel-borderColor', this.borderColor);
```

Is there a better way of setting my CSS variables which can handle multiple instances of the FSC? I've also tried `this.style.setProperty` however, that does not work, and the component fails to render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer posted by Ben Mitchell](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/391707/74992) set me on the right track.

I stopped using the problematic `this.template.host.style` and instead used the  `querySelector()` method scoped to `this.template` to select the element, and then used the `setProperty()` method on the element returned by this.

My updated JS looks like this:

```js
const displayInfoPanel_container = this.template.querySelector('.displayInfoPanel_container');
const displayInfoPanel_icon = this.template.querySelector('.displayInfoPanel_icon');

displayInfoPanel_container.style.setProperty('--displayInfoPanel-borderColor', this.borderColor);
displayInfoPanel_icon.style.setProperty('--displayInfoPanel-iconForegroundColor', this.iconForegroundColor);
displayInfoPanel_icon.style.setProperty('--displayInfoPanel-iconForegroundDefaultColor', this.iconForegroundColor);
displayInfoPanel_icon.style.setProperty('--displayInfoPanel-iconBackgroundColor', this.iconBackgroundColor);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the error is there is an issue with a null value somewhere in one of the `this.template.host.style` lines. I haven't seen `host.style` used in an LWC before, but that's probably my inexperience talking.

For dynamic styling you may also be able to run with a query selector, and then apply styles that way. Use a query selector to target the correct element, and then modify styles as needed.

```
let element = this.template.querySelector('displayInfoPanel');
element.style.borderColor = this.borderColor;
```

Comment: This ultimately worked for me! I targeted the query selector using the element's class name.
and then used the original setProperty method with the updated target.

FYI, there's a typo in your example code, It should be `element.style.borderColor`

Comment: Glad you found your solution! And good catch, I've edited my snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create css class and apply it to html elements. like below -

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    handleClick1(){
        var divblock = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="divblock"]');
        if(divblock){
            this.template.querySelector('[data-id="divblock"]').className='class1';
        }        
    }
    handleClick2(){
        var divblock = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="divblock"]');
        if(divblock){
            this.template.querySelector('[data-id="divblock"]').className='class2';
        }
    }
}
```

I got this from the link [ADDING OR REMOVING CSS CLASS IN LIGHTNING WEB COMPONENT PRAGMATICALLY](https://salesforcediaries.com/2020/05/01/adding-or-removing-css-class-in-lightning-web-component-pragmatically/)

Comment: This is also a great solution for dynamic CSS, but works best in a scenario where the CSS property values are already known. I've used this trick before to get styles on or off an element at a very specific time in the component's lifecycle/usage.